# Cannot propagate row_count from __TABLES__ metadata table to custom table

Tags: google-bigquery

Today I am no longer able to create a table in bigquery from metadata table **TABLES**. Yesterday everything worked fine. Issue can be reproduced using:

```
create or replace table `steady-vine-203410.analysis_us.test`
as
select row_count from `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.__TABLES__`
```

The problem is that during table creation the column row_count is somehow missing. If I try only select without creating the table, everything works.

I have tried doing nested (derived) tables and using WITH clausule, but none of it seems to work today.

Did I miss some bigquery update? Can someone explain to me whats happening or what is the alternative to get row_count of all the tables in a dataset?

Thank you

Comment: I guess you may try to work around by setting query "destination table" to be steady-vine-203410.analysis_us.test if `select row_count from bigquery-public-data.usa_names.__TABLES__` still gives you results. See this: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results

Comment: I was able to run your query twice (modified with my project info of course) successfully (once to confirm I can create new table and second time to see if the replace worked). No issues on my end.

Comment: Today everything seems fine. Query runs successfully without any modification. Thank you for testing :)